# Деструктурирование ...rest из аргументов в объект

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

```
export const setPopup = (...rest) => ({
    type: SET_POPUP,
    payload: {
        ...rest
    }
});
```

1. Стоит ли перекладывать rest-ом все данные, которые передаются в action?
2. И как это сделать?

Answer (score 2):

`rest`- параметры собираются в *массив*.

Деструктуризация его таким образом в объект

```
{
    ...rest
}
```

Даст простой объект, с полями соответствующими ключам массива (0,1,2, ...) и соответствующими значениями.

Сложно придумать, когда это может понадобиться.

Максимум, это можно использоваться к качестве *создания копии* массива

```
[...rest]
```

либо передавать `rest` напрямую в `payload`.

Comment: Это же аргументы - они уже всегда копия? Или можно исхитриться вызвать так, чтоб этот массив был ссылочно равен массиву в другом месте?

Comment: @Qwertiy, я вообще имел ввиду, что если внутри функции эта переменная еще используется, и может меняться. Да, сейчас проверил, при сравнении с переданным аргументом - всегда разные ссылки